# Swagger UI Get Request with @RequestBody

Tags: swagger-ui, springfox

I am using Swagger springfox version 2.5.0. Everything works pretty fine, except one thing. When a GET request method has @RequestBody Swagger UI throws this exception

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException
```

The same GET command works perfectly fine with curl command. Is this a issue with Swagger UI or am I missing something here.

thanks

Comment: Try to update to 2.6.1 and show us your controller.

Comment: Hi, I tried with 2.6.1 also, but didn't work. Here is my controller.
`@ApiOperation(value = "Solr keyword search", nickname = "searchByKeyword")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/searchByKeyword", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<SearchResponse> searchByKeyword(@Valid @RequestBody KeywordSearchRequest request) {

.....
    .....
    }`